# Convert Google fonts path to SVG path

Tags: javascript, svg, opentype

I am trying to follow the example at https://github.com/danmarshall/google-font-to-svg-path to render create an Google Font as an svg. My code is as follows:

```
opentype.load('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=' + 'ABeeZee', (err, font) => {
  const textModel = new makerjs.models.Text(font, 'Test', 20, false, false, 1);
  const svg = makerjs.exporter.toSVG(textModel);
  console.log(svg);
});
```

I keep getting the error message: `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEachGlyph' of null`, how do I fix it? My code is based on the example here: https://github.com/danmarshall/google-font-to-svg-path/blob/master/index.ts#L73-L97.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it as follows:

```
const url = 'http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/quicksand/v21/6xK-dSZaM9iE8KbpRA_LJ3z8mH9BOJvgkKEo18G0wx40QDw.ttf';
const text = 'hello';
const size = 14;
const union = false;
const bezierAccuracy = 0;
let svg = null;
opentype.load(url, (err, font) => {
  const textModel = new makerjs.models.Text(font, text, size, union, false, bezierAccuracy);
  svg = makerjs.exporter.toSVG(textModel);
});
return svg;
```